# Improve Excel peformance for calculation

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel 2010 for calculation of subset. I'm using a formula with COUNTIF and checking if any of 21,000 numbers from column B are among 300,000 numbers in column A. My system is running Win 7 with two processors 4 GB RAM but simply hangs doing the calculations. I can't do anything else while it calculates because it takes ~ 100% of CPU.

Is this calculation so CPU consuming or I could do something to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One fast way: Sort the 300000 numbers in column A and use the Double Vlookup trick to see if there are any exact matches: see this post on my blog for details of how to do it:

https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/vlookup-tricks-why-2-vlookups-are-better-than-1-vlookup/

Comment: I don't know ... why would that be required?

Comment: Charles, could you please help me to understand VLOOKUP better? I never used it before. E.g. I have a table with columns A and B. The value in A are 1,2,3. In column B are 3,4,1. I wrote this: =IF(VLOOKUP(A1,$A$1:$B$3,1,TRUE)=A1,"EXISTS","MISSING") But it returned me EXIST for all 3 rows which is wrong. How should I write to get EXIST only for 1 and 3 ? Thanks

Comment: You want to lookup B in column A not A in Column A: try =IF(VLOOKUP(B1,$A$1:$B$3,1,TRUE)=B1,"EXISTS","MISSING")

Comment: It worked as you suggested. It also worked when I used 'FALSE' instead of 'TRUE' ... BUT if I understood correctly from your article the point to improve performance is to use only 'TRUE', Am I correct?